# What does it mean to simplify a polynomial division?

Tags: polynomials, algebra-precalculus

I am doing my homework and have encountered this problem: $\frac{3x^5+5x^4+x+5}{x+2}$. I am asked to simplify it. However, when I tried to divide, it did not divide evenly, and there is a remainder. How should I put my final answer? Should I just do $\frac{3x^5+5x^4+x+5}{x+2}$, or put $3x^4-x^3+2x^2-4x+9-\frac{13}{x+2}$?

Comment: P.S. I am planning to do the latter one.

Comment: The latter one is more useful, e.g., if you have to integrate the whole thing.

Comment: (and you have no mistakes, the denominator does not go into the numerator, as $-2$ is not a root of the numerator)

Comment: Therefore it does not simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last expression is as simple as it gets! Doing all of the polynomial "simplified" it from what you were given. Looks good!